# How to import steps using HealthKit from Apple watch in offline mode?

Tags: ios, healthkit, watchos

Step count reported via Apple Watch is only accessible after syncing with iPhone. Is there any way that I can replicate HealthKit step data on to my own watch app in offline mode( Watch not connected with iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

All the HealthKit API's for querying step data are available on watchOS as well. Just do something similar to what your phone app is doing, but in the WatchKit extension code.